# How to get customer default shipping and billing address data (i am after country and postcode)

Tags: customer, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

I have customer ID - Not sure how to grab the default shipping/billing address.
I can get the current shipping address and billing address but not the default.
Is there any way I could get the default shipping and billing details?